# Javamail using OAuth and GMail

Tags: java, email, oauth

I've been working on a java application to use my Gmail connection to send an email but am hitting a wall.

I've found out that I need to use OAuth which the current implementation of JavaMail uses, but I haven't really found a clear cut guide to how to do this.  I'm an amateur programmer and well, kind of a dummy when it comes to comprehension (I'm working really hard for some C's in school, lol)  but I'm trying to learn here.

Most of what I've put together has been culled from other things I've found, trying to get something working, which it kind of is.  But the problem that I'm hitting is one of two things.

Either I can't get authorized, then I get an email from Google saying an app was trying to access my email without complying with modern security standards, or that I need to log in via a web browser.

From what I've found, a few years back Google changed their security which is why we need to use OAuth now, which, luckily JavaMail supports, but I can't get it working.  And a lot of the help I've seen here on Stack Overflow or other places is nearly 5 years old.

Right now, I'm trying to make a java program in eclipse to just send an email, and I'm using github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools

To try and make the OAuth token, but there's an error

[Error Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbJmz.png)

The method in OAuth2SaslClientFactory

```
    public SaslClient createSaslClient(String[] mechanisms,
        String authorizationId,
        String protocol,
        String serverName,
        Map<String, ?> props,
        CallbackHandler callbackHandler) {
    boolean matchedMechanism = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < mechanisms.length; ++i) {
        if ("XOAUTH2".equalsIgnoreCase(mechanisms[i])) {
            matchedMechanism = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!matchedMechanism) {
        logger.info("Failed to match any mechanisms");
        return null;
    }
    return new OAuth2SaslClient((String)props.get(OAUTH_TOKEN_PROP), callbackHandler);
}
```

The code from OAuth2SASLClient

```
    public OAuth2SaslClient(String oauthToken, CallbackHandler callbackHandler) {
this.oauthToken = oauthToken;
this.callbackHandler = callbackHandler;  }
```

That return line is saying the constructor can't handle that, but the constructor in OAuth2SaSLClient.java is actually set up to have a (String, Callback) parameter.

If somebody has something quick and easy that works, I'd love to see it,even though it appears that this needs to use a specific way of creating an OAuth token.

I can post my code if it helps, but I need to clean it up first, it's sort of a first draft / messy collage of things I've tried to get working.

Or a javamail / Oauth tutorial for dummies.

The end goal here is to tie this to a program that can send out a quick notification when something happens.  Which I can't seem to do.

Comment: Instead of sharing the code as images, it will help if you share the code here itself using `code blocks`

Answer (score 0):

Mixing OAuth and javamail won't work, you need to choose your API: either the Gmail v4 API (with OAuth) or the javamail API.  You said you are just trying to send emails from your own account, so I'd suggest you use the javamail IMAP API.  When going through the javamail API you don't need Oauth at all.

For example:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(GOOGLE_USERNAME, password);
        }
});


Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM_EMAIL, FROM_NAME));
// rest of the email settings
```

If you needed to send emails on behalf of other people, or need to do more advanced mail operations such as create a Gmail draft, then the Gmail API would be the proper approach.

Note: if you are going to use the *Gmail API*, be sure to use the newer Gmail API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java

The old *Google Data API* is deprecated